# Does TextToSpeech.setLanguage("en_US") always succeed?

Tags: android, localization, locale, text-to-speech, speech

In Android API 19+, when using the method:

```
TextToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale locale)
```

...can we assume that setting the speech locale to "en_US" will always succeed (and allow for speech to actually happen on the device in English) on any device anywhere in the world?

Answer (score 2):

The `TextToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale locale)` call from a frontend application is directed by the System level TTS API to the currently selected TTS engine, the engine is then responsible for providing a response on whether it supports that locale. Most engines allow for the installation of additional voice packs so if your device doesn't support the locale you are looking for, you may possibly download a voice in that locale.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.  I'm taking that as a "No," also.  I have learned a lot since writing this question... and it seems like you know quite a bit about TTS.  I have lots of other recent, unanswered questions on TTS if you would like to take a look I would really appreciate any input.

Answer (score 1):

My personal experience: NO.

Google break something in TTS engine and now it uses current user locale instead of provided one.

I'm not sure is it works well before but on modern android devices setLocale doesn't work at all.